# how to cast to "this" type from base to derived class

Tags: c++

I want to retrieve the initial type in the base class `A` because the method `encodeMsg()` will have tasks that are related to the derived type

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>




    struct base {

    };

    struct derive : base {

    };

    class A{
    public:
        A(){}
        virtual void encode() {
            encodeMsg(_bStruct);
            // here I want to cast base to derive but I don't know how I tried
            // static_cast<decltype(this)>(_bStruct) but it seems doesn't work
        }

        virtual void setStruct(base* bStruct) {
            _bStruct = bStruct;
        }
    private:

        virtual void encodeMsg(base* bStruct) = 0;

        protected:

            base* _bStruct;

    };

    class B : public A {
    public:
        B(){}
        void encodeMsg(base* bStruct) {
            derive* _dStruct = static_cast<derive*>(bStruct);
            // ..
            // stuff within dervied struct

            _bStruct = static_cast<base*>(_dStruct); // turn back to base struct
        }

    };

    int main() {

        B b;
        base* _bStruct = new derive();
        b.setStruct(_bStruct);
        b.encode();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `derive* d = dynamic_cast<derive*>(_bStruct); if (d != nullptr) { ... }`?

Comment: `A` is pure virtual class using by many sub classes I cant use specefic `dynamic_cast<derive*>(_bStruct)` inside because there are other derive1, derive2 .. etc

Comment: You should consider to make `A::encode` pure virtual and to implement the derived class specific part in the derived class(es). Only the derived class(es) know the actual type and can cast the pointer to the specific class type.

Comment: @anes47 Do you want to customize this code for each derived class or not? If so, I explained how you do it. If not, what would be the purpose of the cast?

Comment: Or, think of the basic algorithm for encoding a msg, `{EncodeHeader(); EncodeBody(); EncodeTail();}` and make THOSE virtual.  The "pieces parts" that you care about can be addressed in one (two or all three)?  That way, the encodeMsg can basically be the "same" for all derived types (or keep it virtual if that basic algorithm is not valid for some special case derived class).

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no sense.

In your code, the only thing you could do with the pointer, if you could create it, is access members known to be in the base class. But you can do that already without the pointer. So what purpose does the pointer serve?

If you want to one thing if it's a `derived1` and something else if it's a `derived2`, then you need to use one piece of code for the `derived1` case and one piece of code for the `derived2` case.

If you want to do the same thing regardless of what derived type it is, there is no need for the cast you seek. The code *in this function* will be the same regardless of what the derived type is.

If you want code that only works if the derived type is some specific type, use a `dynamic_cast` to a pointer to that type and write the specific code. If you want code that works regardless of the derived type, use a pointer to an instance of the base class.

**Update**:

To access members not in `base` but in a `derived1`, use this code:

```
    virtual void encode() {
        derived1* d1 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(bStruct);
        if (d1 != nullptr)
        {
            // here you can access d1->whatever
        }
    }
```

Comment: the purpose of casting that I did in the function `encodeMsg` is so that I can access methods and / or members of the derived class that are not defined in the base class. my question is how I can retrieve the derive object via the base class

Comment: @anes47 That is precisely what I explained with my first comment on your question. If you want to access members of `derived1` that are not in the base class, you need to use a `dynamic_cast` to a `derived1*`. To access types only in `derived1`, you need a `derived1*`.

Comment: I understand what do you mean. but I think it's not proper to put a derived type in the base class. imagine that I am using another type derive2 ! 
that's why i want to do the cast this way. `dynamic_cast<TYPEOF(this)>(bStruct)`